# How to make input fields display in the same row in an HTML card?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

How can I make Quarter and Month display in the same row, as well as Week and Date in a row right below?

```html
<base target="_top">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<div id="cardsContainer">
  <div class="card-group">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quarter" value="1">
          <label for="monthNum">Month:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="monthNum" value="2"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="weekNum">Week:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="weekNum" value="4">
          <label for="date">Date:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" value="12/31/1969">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="status">Status:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status" value="Planned">
          </div>
          <a href="https://tesla-cdn.thron.com/delivery/public/image/tesla/03e533bf-8b1d-463f-9813-9a597aafb280/bvlatuR/std/4096x2560/M3-Homepage-Desktop-LHD"><img src="https://tesla-cdn.thron.com/delivery/public/image/tesla/03e533bf-8b1d-463f-9813-9a597aafb280/bvlatuR/std/4096x2560/M3-Homepage-Desktop-LHD" class="card-img" height="180px"></a>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="post">Post:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="post" style="height: 444px;">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum /
          </textarea></div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="publishedPostLink">Published Link:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="publishedPostLink" value="https://posts.gle/nTUL97">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" hidden="">
          <label for="postNum">Post Number:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postNum" value="1">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please reformat your code so it is easier to see what is in those `form-group` divs

Comment: Sorry about that, @JonP! Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the **Quarter** and **Month** display in the same row and the **Week** and **Date** in another row, you can use the Bootstrap grid system. Add a "row" class to wrap the two groups of inputs, and use **"col-sm-6"** class for each input group to make them span half of the row on small devices:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="quarter">Quarter:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="quarter" value="1">
        <label for="monthNum">Month:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="monthNum" value="2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="weekNum">Week:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="weekNum" value="4">
        <label for="date">Date:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" value="12/31/1969">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- rest of the form -->
  </form>
</div>
```